# T-SQL table type, specified type not registered

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-types

I have a query written as a string in C# that I'm attempting to call on a T-sql database (not a stored procedure). One of the parameters I have to pass in is a list of GUIDs. I'm attempting to use a [table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) for this. Given that part of the query requires dynamic table names a stored procedure is considered somewhat clunky for debugging. The final part of the query joins the ID on the table to the list of Guids I'm passing in.

Adding the parameter to my command in

```
var ListOfIDs = new DataTable();
    ListOfIDs.Columns.Add("ID", typeof (Guid));
    selectedIDs.ForEach(x=> ListOfIDs.Rows.Add(x));

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ListOfIDs", SqlDbType.Udt)
{
   Value = ListOfIDs, UdtTypeName = "ListOfGuids"
});
```

My table

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ListOfGuids] AS TABLE(
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL
)
```

When I run the line:

```
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I get the error:

> Specified type is not registered on the target server.System.Data.DataTable, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.

I have been unable to locate what I need to do to get this working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using `SqlDbType.Structured`. `.Udt` is not a table-valued parameter or table type, that's a CLR User-Defined Type IIRC. A TVP / table-valued parameter is an **alias type** not a **user-defined type**. You also don't need to tell it the `.UdtTypeName` because, again, this has nothing to do with TVPs, and your code shouldn't be mentioning `Udt` in any shape or form.

If your procedure looks like this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProcedure
  @ListOfGUIDs dbo.ListOfGuids READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  ...
END
```

Then your C# code can be:

```
SqlCommand cmd       = new SqlCommand("dbo.MyProcedure", conn);
cmd.CommandType      = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlParameter tvparam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ListOfGUIDs", ListOfIDs);
tvparam.SqlDbType    = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

Or, if you just have a statement, like `SELECT * FROM @ListOfGUIDs` then:

```
SqlCommand cmd       = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM @ListOfGUIDs", conn);
cmd.CommandType      = CommandType.Text;
SqlParameter tvparam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ListOfGUIDs", ListOfIDs);
tvparam.SqlDbType    = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

Comment: If that's the case, how do I define which DB type I'm using? Do I still use the UdtTypeName?

Comment: @DocSmiley you don't need to define that in the C# code - that should be defined in the input parameter for the stored procedure.

Comment: I'm specifically not using a stored procedure. I have a built string in C# that is getting passed as the command text.

Comment: @DocSmiley that doesn't really change much about what I'm telling you at all, except that the CommandType wouldn't be a stored procedure. Maybe if you show the actual string you're building in C# you will get help more tailored to your actual problem (maybe you can explain why you don't want to use a stored procedure for something like this, too).

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt responses.